# How to go to Previous Screen of the page in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to handle History in React ?
I have a home Page with Listing of event data from API. I scroll down and go to detail Page of a specific Event. Now when i click browser back button the home component loads again and all data is fetch again from server.
I want to go the last visited screen of the home page when back button is clicked.
How to handle this case in React ? Same like facebook do.

Comment: Can you add some code snippets?

Comment: Look at routing solutions for `React` applications.

Comment: How do you handle routing right now?

Comment: If you don't want to fetch all data again then you should not change component at the first play I think.

Comment: Not sure that I understand which behavior you are trying to implement. but it looks like you are looking for some routing solution. There are several approaches that could be used for SPA, but it's quite common to use html5 history for that. You can check this popular library https://reactrouter.com/

Comment: I am using react routers

Answer (score 0):

Since routing normally will unmount the component after redirecting, the data will be lost and the component is unaware if the data was just fetched.
I order to avoid the fetch again, you have several options

1. To keep the fetch state in an higher component in the hierarchy. E.g.: Redux store, wrapper, etc.
2. Keep some kind of [cache](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/caching#_top) (and show this cache meanwhile you are fetching again)